# phpmailer class send invalid character from database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli, phpmailer

i work with PHPMailer Class for send email like this :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = _MAIL_SMTP_HOST_;                       // Specify main and backup server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = _MAIL_SMTP_USER_;                   // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = _MAIL_SMTP_PASS_;               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
        $mail->Port = _MAIL_SMTP_PORT_;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
        $mail->setFrom(_MAIL_SMTP_FROM_, _MAIL_SMTP_FROM_NAME_);     //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->addAddress(_MAIL_SMTP_TO_, _MAIL_SMTP_TO_NAME_); 
        $mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);     
        $mail->addAttachment($file);        // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = $altbody;
        if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
        }
```

i send body message from my database but in email i see this output :

```
????????
```

how do PHPMailer work with `utf-8` characters?

**NOTE** : i have this for mysql : `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` and MySqli : `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` i check with both (mysql and mysqli)

Comment: *" i have this for mysql : mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); and MySqli : $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") i check with both (mysql and mysqli)"* - You're mixing APIs, don't.

Comment: RTFM: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=properties   `$mail->Charset()`. just because mysql's been set to utf8 doesn't relieve you of having to tell the email (and the recipient) what charset to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: No!! i Have two class for `mysql` and `mysqli` and i can change both for My Query.

Comment: Read what Marc said then.

Comment: @MarcB: your mean is : change `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` to `$mail->Charset()`?

Comment: @o-O: ah man, sorry. I totally missed that line.

Comment: @o-O what is the collation of table field in which you are saving data?

Comment: @ApulGupta: utf8_general_ci